# Google Home Customization Feasibility

Tags: android, google-home, google-smart-home

My company is experiencing a difficult selection for our smart home solution. The reqiurement is as following:

1. We will build our own voice assitant with a drip-off pad(Like Amazon Echo Show 10/Goolge Nest Hub) hardware, with Android OS in it
2. we would like to support basic voice interactions like asking weather, traffic...,based on the common knowledgebase, we would like to build our own KB which focus on the health part.
3. We already finalized our hardware, with mics and speakers array ready, and we tried to leverage Amazon(Alex), but it has many restrictions to do that. Then I look into Google Home solution, but it looks like we have to use Google's hardware to use all the SDK of GHA.
4. My company built few other health management IOT devices, would like to be controled by our voice assistant.
   My question is that Google Home is the proper solution for my case? Or any other alternative one? Thanks in advance since I am quite new to Smart Home solution.

Answer (score 1):

- As per my understanding you are trying to address two issues.

  - First, enabling a voice assistant feature in your products.
  - Second, being able to control your devices.
- For voice assistant goals you can make use of the following [resource](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/).
- For device control you can check out the following [resource](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a matter of controlling IoT devices by issuing simple voice commands or viewing sensor readings you can have a look at my platform [chipchop.io](https://chipchop.io)

It integrates only with Alexa (no GHA yet) and currently supports most of the basic device types, it doesn't really care what you've plugged at the other end (Arduino, PI, Android, Node...) or even if it is a physical device.

You are free to use it to experiment and for commercial projects it can be customised and expanded on request, ping me a message there through the contact form and I'l be happy to advise.